# Use Metadata API to search based on location of artist?

Tags: spotify

I've been told that according to Spotify, you can build a playlist based on geolocation. I'm not finding anything in the documentation or the response data to figure out how to do this. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who told you that? Spotify has no Geo features - without using an external API that'll give you a location of an artist, you can't do what you're asking with the Spotify APIs.

Comment: Thanks, iKenndac. I waited to check this until the person who told me that looked here. I already knew the answer, but sometimes people need to hear what they don't want to hear from more than one person.